# What. Is. This. Style. Called?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-style, terminology

I see this style rather frequently and in the past decade many print advertisements have apparently decided that it makes their sentences. have. more. impact. I can tell that the style is trying to mimic a very specific spoken word pattern that accentuates every. single. word. But I don't know if this writing style has a name.

I am specifically interested in the *written* variant that uses periods throughout a sentence in order to emphasize each word.

Comment: That question doesn't actually have an appropriate answer, though. :P

Comment: Yeah, but it's still a duplicate. Maybe this'll bump it enough to acquire a good answer.

Comment: This question has been asked in other places, too, and I have not seen a valid answer.  The best invalid answer is "a massive failure of the internet," found here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090126180002AAPakUd -- don't click the link on that page unless you want to be Rick-Rolled.

Comment: @Marthaª: I don't think that's a very good policy here. Most of our questions don't state the matter very well, and most of our answers are not much better. Banning a question as a duplicate simply because somebody has asked it before and not gotten a good answer **prevents** good answers.

Comment: By the way, there's no special name for this style. It's simply an attempt to make pronunciation and capitalization represent a very specialized "tone of voice" with emphatic emotional purport.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I don't know if closing as dupe prevents good answers - it merely ensures that you only have to look in one place for answers, including (hopefully) the good ones. That said, you can always nominate this question for reopening. :)

Comment: Whatever gave you the idea that you only have to look in one place here for answers? Are there statistics on this, or is it only an assumption?

Comment: @JohnLawler: obviously, the *goal* is to have to look in only one place for answers to a single question. Just because we don't always reach said goal doesn't mean we shouldn't keep trying.

Comment: So, you're saying there are no statistics and this goal is purely theoretical. Is there any evidence that it has ever worked, and that there is some reason _why_ "we should keep trying"? It seems to me to have no effect on information in the group, except to keep it from being passed out.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd call it "Emphatically. Irritating. Style."  Really.